# I cannot remove this virus

Tags: virus

I have tried Farbar scan, I have tried MalwareBytes, I have been able to get into registry at one point and remove all of what I thought was infecting it. I ran Kaspersky, CCleaner, and TDS killer. Nothing is working to get rid of this virus. The virus also morphed and now  I can't click ctrl+alt+del after starting a scan and try to close, which was allowing me to say "no" so I could get back in.

Comment: How do you know it's a virus, vs just a corrupted OS install?

Answer (score 0):

Use [Autoruns](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb963902.aspx) to examine all of the startup items and remove any suspicious ones. You can save the report (File -> Save) and upload it here if you're not sure which ones to remove. If you can't run Autoruns from the infected PC, then you can use a Live CD such as a [custom made WinPE](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc709665%28v=ws.10%29.aspx), or [BartPE](http://www.nu2.nu/pebuilder/) by going to File -> Analyze Offline System in Autoruns.